# TSQLQuery inserta registro vacio en MySQL

Tags: delphi

Estoy trabajando en Delphi y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    try
     conexion:=TConexion.Create();

    finally
       with DataModule1.qinsertproducto do
      begin
        close;
        sql.Clear;
        SQL.Add('INSERT INTO producto (nombre,unidad,precio,stock,idcat,idmarca,codalfa,aliiva,idsubcat,granel,contenido)');
        SQL.Add(' VALUES  (nombre=:nombre,unidad="u",precio=:precio,stock=:stock,idcat=:idcat,idmarca=:idmarca,codalfa=:codalfa,aliiva=:aliiva,idsubcat=0,granel="n",contenido="1")');
        Params.ParamByName('nombre').Value:=nombre;
        Params.ParamByName('precio').AsFloat:=precio;
        Params.ParamByName('stock').AsFloat:=stock;
        Params.ParamByName('idcat').AsInteger:=cat;
        Params.ParamByName('idmarca').AsInteger:=marca;
        Params.ParamByName('codalfa').AsString:=codalfa;
        Params.ParamByName('aliiva').AsFloat:=iva;

        ExecSQL();
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Para la conexion uso e patron singleton. Lo comparto por las dudas si tiene algo que ver:

```
unit SingleConexion;

interface

type
TConexion = class
 private
class var _instance: TConexion;
 public
//Global point of access to the unique instance
class function Create: TConexion;

destructor Destroy; override;
 end;

 implementation

 { TSingleton }

 uses MODULODATOS,IniFiles,Forms,Dialogs,Sysutils;

class function TConexion.Create: TConexion;
var
 ini:TIniFile;

begin
  if (_instance = nil) then
   begin
     ini:=TInifile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'caja.ini');
   with DataModule1.CONEXION do
   begin
        Close;
        DriverName:='MySQL';
        Params.Values['UserName']:=ini.ReadString('admin','User','');
        Params.Values['Password']:=ini.ReadString('admin','Pass','');

        Params.Values['HostName']:=ini.ReadString('admin','IP','');
        Params.Values['DataBase']:=ini.ReadString('admin','bd','');
        Params.Values['Port']:=ini.ReadString('admin','Port','3306');
        Open;

 end;


   _instance:= inherited Create as Self;

  end;
 result:= _instance;
end;

destructor TConexion.Destroy;
 begin
  _instance:= nil;
 inherited;
 end;

end.
```

El caso es que el idproducto es autoincremental y los valores de las variables asignadas a los parametros si llegan porque los probe con un ShowMessage.
Pero me inserta un registro nuevo con todos los campos vacios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo intentaría centrarme en la parte del `INSERT`.

1. Añade `try..except` para saber si se genera algun error en la ejecución (no está el código completo y no se si lo tienes ya capturado).
2. Añade el parámetro de retorno al `ExecSQL` que normalmente devuelve el número de registros insertados.
3. Intenta ejecutar la consulta sin parámetros para ver si el registro se añade correctamente. Con eso puedes descartar si los problemas los generan los parámetros.

Comment: Me faltaban agregar los parametros manualmente en el componente TSQLQuery. Pero ahora obtengo "dbExpress driver does not support the TDBXTypes.UNKNOWN data type. Vendor error message: ." Aunque todos tienen el tipo definido

Comment: Prueba a utilizar .Value en todos los ParamByName

Comment: Ok ahi lo hice y finalmente se soluciono. Gracias una vez mas amigo.